# How to test string array?

Tags: c#

I have a text file that has three columns primarily. In some rows there are only two columns with data. I extract the file content into an array of strings.

I print `txttxtOUIsearchResults.AppendText(t[0] + " - " + t[2] + Environment.NewLine);` with no issue. However, if the string array has only `t[0]` and `t[1]`, I will get an exception.

Is there a way to test if the array contains three strings and to do something else rather than throwing an exception if it doesn't?

```cs
// Search results from the list.
List<string> SearchResults = texter.FindAll(o => o.StartsWith(strExpand));
// The foreach will locate multiple lines if it exist within the text file.
foreach (string value in SearchResults)
{

    var t = value.Split('\t'); // 3 string arrays.

    var CkEmpty = t[2]; // Just one of 20 things I test that don't work.

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CkEmpty)) // However, sometimes there's only two string arrays. If only two then it will error.
    {
        // Permit the textbox control to run in a thread.
        txttxtOUIsearchResults.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            txttxtOUIsearchResults.AppendText(t[0] + " - " + t[1] + Environment.NewLine);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Permit the textbox control to run in a thread.
        txttxtOUIsearchResults.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            txttxtOUIsearchResults.AppendText(t[0] + " - " + t[2] + Environment.NewLine);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just check the `Length` property of the array to know how many elements it has. If it's less than 3, you skip checking t[2].

Comment: remove `var CkEmpty = t[2]` and check with `if (t.Length < 3)` instead

Comment: var CkEmpty = (t.Length < 3)?"":t[2]; this should fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you always want the first and the last value in your string, regardles if there are 2 or 3 values. So:

```
 // Search results from the list.
 List<string> SearchResults = texter.FindAll(o => o.StartsWith(strExpand));
 // The foreach will locate multiple lines if it exist within the text file.
 foreach (string value in SearchResults)
 {
 
     var t = value.Split('\t'); // 2-3 string arrays.

     txttxtOUIsearchResults.Invoke((Action)delegate
         {
             txttxtOUIsearchResults.AppendText(t[0] + " - " + t[t.Length - 1] + Environment.NewLine);
         });
 }
```